# Removing last trailing ", " in Liquid

Tags: shopify, liquid

I've put together this code for Shopify that creates a string containing all the variant image src's apparent in a product. It then compares this list to the overall `product.media` object and "filters out" the images that share the same URL as the variant images, so that I get a string that only contains URL's for images not associated with a variant. I can then use this final string/array with a for loop that only outputs images not connected to a variant, for example to use with a gallery that only should contain "general images" of the product.

The code for creating this looks like this:

```
{% comment %}
  Filter out images that is not variant images for gallery use

  variant_image_srcs: String that contains all variant image srcs
  gallery_images: String that created with a for loop and contains images that doesn't match it's src with any of the variant_image_srcs
  gallery_images_array: String that's split and ready to be used with for loop using for example 'image | product_img_url: '1000x' filter

{% endcomment %}
{% capture variant_image_srcs %}
{% for variant in product.variants %}
  {% if variant.featured_image.id != null %}
  {{variant.featured_image.src }}{% if forloop.last != true %}, {% endif %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% endcapture %}

{% capture gallery_images %}
  {% for media in product.media %}
    {% unless variant_image_srcs contains media.preview_image.src %}
      {{media.preview_image.src }}{% if forloop.last != true %}, {% endif %}
    {% endunless %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endcapture %}

{% assign gallery_images_array = gallery_images | split: ", " %}
```

The captured `gallery_images` is using this not so optimal line: `{% if forloop.last != true %}, {% endif %}` that puts a `,`  at the end of each item, in order to differentiate them. The problem is that the last `media.preview_image.src` that should be added to the string is not always the last item in the for loop, causing the captured string to have this trailing `,`  that outputs an image that can't be found, as there are no `image.src` with the string `,` .

I guess the same problem would apply to the first for loop if the `variant.featured_image.id != null` would return `false`.

Is there a way to remove an exact set of characters (in this case ', ') from the right of a string in Liquid or how can I otherwise do this so that ', ' is not added to the last truthy item?

Hope you understand the problem and I would love to get some input on how to make this more waterproof and effective.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another possible approach besides the above answer is to use [remove_first](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/liquid/reference/filters/string-filters#remove_first) string filter. But for that, you would have to append comma first and then image src. You can just remove the if condition then.

```
{%- capture gallery_images -%}
  {%- for media in product.media -%}
    {%- unless variant_image_srcs contains media.preview_image.src -%}
      {{media.preview_image.src | prepend: "," }}
    {%- endunless %}
  {%- endfor %}
{%- endcapture -%}

{%- assign gallery_images_array = gallery_images| remove_first: "," | split: "," -%}
```

Comment: That's a nice idea! The `gallery_images_array` only outputs the first image after applying these changes though.

Comment: @tobiasg can you check now ? I think there was an extra space after comma in split filter in my code.

Comment: Yes, that worked! I think there needs to be an extra space after `gallery_images` in the last row as well, but maybe the code runs fine without it. Would you recommend to make any changes to the first capture statement? Maybe this logic could be applied to that as well?

Comment: Yes you can. I am not sure about the *variant.featured_image* logic, but besides that if you are just getting an additional comma , you can adjust that in the same manner.

Answer (score 0):

There is an interesting feature or bug in liquid that you can use in your case.

When you split a string based a specific hook if there is nothing after that string that element is excluded from the array.

For example: `1,2,3,4,` if we split it by `,` we expect top get `[1,2,3,4,'']`, but we actually get `[1,2,3,4]`, the last item is removed automatically since it's empty.

This only works if this is the LAST item, it doesn't work if it's the first or somewhere else.

In your case this probably doesn't work since you have too much white spaces around the liquid tags. So instead of using just `{%  %}` use `{%-  -%}` this will automatically strip white spaces and new lines.

So your tags should become like so:

`{%- capture -%} / {%- if -%} / {%- for -%} / {%- endcapture -%} / {%- endif -%} / {%- ednfor -%}`

Comment: Are you sure about it? Let say we have `string = '1,2,3,4,'` `array = string | split: ','`. When we join the array again, we still get the original string `{{array}}` => `1,2,3,4,`

Answer (score 0):

Simple Approach:

Just [append](https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/filters/string-filters?shpxid=72e49efa-50BC-4FBF-E8AB-966107E0D071) another random character (e.g. #END), and simply [remove](https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/filters/string-filters?shpxid=72e49efa-50BC-4FBF-E8AB-966107E0D071#remove) it at last.

```
{% assign variant_image_srcs = "" %}
{% for variant in product.variants %}
{% if variant.featured_image.id != null %}
    {% assign variant_image_srcs = variant_image_srcs | append: variant.featured_image.src | append: ", " %}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% assign variant_image_srcs = variant_image_srcs | append: "#END" %}
{% assign variant_image_srcs = variant_image_srcs | remove: ", #END" %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my answer:

```
{% assign length = gallery_images | size | minus: 2 %}
{% assign outputstring = gallery_images | truncate: length, "" %}
```